# 'Script Table as' in SSMS Not Preserving Collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to get the 'Script Table as' > 'CREATE To' option for tables in SQL Server Management Studio to preserve the collation types set for each column?

I know it's possible to specify collation types for columns when creating tables so I find it odd that these settings aren't present in the script output by SSMS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options.

Expand "Sql Server Object Explorer" -> Scripting and there is an option "Include collation" you can enable there in the "Table and view options" category (the default value is false).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Works also on new versions of SSMS, but there is a downside: the collation will be explicitly included even if the column is <default database collation>

Comment: This is an old thread, but thanks so much for the response.  I needed case sensitivity in a primary key and used SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS for a small number of fields.  The fact that create tables didn't include the collation almost broke me.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the database in Management Studio ---> Tasks --> Generate Scripts.

On the final page of the wizard there is an Advanced button, which has a bunch of options, one of which is script collation.

[image]

Comment: This is useful if you you don't want to always script the collation for each table but you have one particular table you do want to script it for.

Answer (score 0):

In [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) 19 the dialogue looks like this

[image: Tools Options in SSMS 19]

Enter `Scripting` in the seach box and open `Table and View Options`

[image: Tools/Options - Scripting]